# Use code markdown for "highlight" words or no?

Tags: discussion, support, markdown

I used markdown (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>) in some words. I keep using markdown or is better use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>?

(
Estou usando marcação de código (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>) em algumas palavras. Devo continuar usando marcação de código ou devo usar <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> e <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>?
)

Eg.:

```
`Portuguese word`
```

Or

```
*Portuguese word*
```

Or

```
**Portuguese word**
```

Answer (score 4):

**Proposal.** In the title, no formatting is available, so let's use quote marks; and in the body of a post,

```
*[Any language] word* or *[Any language] expression*
```

which puts the text in italics.

**Comment.** It's not great, since a reader might miss this formatting in the middle of a sentence. I had to rearrange my whole [question](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/370/6) to avoid having *a* in the middle of a sentence, for example. On the plus-side, it is not obtrusive.

Comment: This is the best way. One uses italics where possible and quotes otherwise. Code markdown looks abominable in this context.

Answer (score 1):

One use of code formatting I've seen here that I find attractive and useful is for **referring to orthography.** For example, using `nh` (instead of using **nh** or *nh* or [nh] or "nh") to refer to the digraph, or `-` (instead of "-") to refer to a hyphen.

I feel strongly that it shouldn't be used to emphasize words or ideas, as there are already more appropriate ways to do that (*italics*, **bold**, section headings).

Comment: Although I don’t see why italics aren’t good enough —for example, written *nh* is pronounced /ɲ/—there is also the notation of using angle quotes for text literals, which then becomes written ‹nh› is pronounced /ɲ/. These are the two styles used in scholarly texts, and I see no reason to resort to anything else. Both italics and angle quotes are unobtrusive measures which comfortably fit the “color” of the page’s typography. You ***never*** see reference works or linguistics papers `using ugly constant-width fonts with ugly highlighter effects applied`. It makes text resemble a ransom letter.

Comment: Yeah, angle quotes are probably better. I just thought the code formatting looked nice in this very narrow case.

Comment: Anyone know how to write angle quotes on a US keyboard?

Comment: @brazilianldsjaguar I never try: I always just ‹grab›  with a ‹mouse› .